# Spring scope usage for instance variables

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc

We are implementing spring services and the @Webservice layer is singleton and it calls a 'Service' layer which is a prototype. The Service layer has a lot of instance variables so, thought making it a prototype would be ideal, but, it looks like that prototype is instantiated only one time because @Webservice layer is singleton.

What type of @Scope works for us? We have a lot of instance variables on service layer and it is hard for us to make them local to method as a lot of code needs to change because of this.

If I make all layers as singleton, do two thread share the instance variables?

Comment: A scoped-proxy prototype.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis could you please elaborate?

Comment: [Scoped beans as dependencies](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis is there an equivalent for this in annotation?

Comment: Yes, `@org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope`.

Comment: Singletons are shared across everything, there is exactly 1 application wide. And what scope you would need depends on when your service needs to "reset" it's fields. Maybe per request? Tbh, it sounds a bit like you should rather change your code.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thank you.! that did the trick. Please post answer, i'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a singleton bean with an injection target, Spring will initialize the bean and inject the field/method/constructor immediately. If that injection target is a prototype bean, Spring will do so exactly once.

Presumably, you want a new prototype bean on each action or event that your singleton handles. You'll need an AOP scoped proxy. This is documented in the Spring chapter on [Scoped proxies and dependencies](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection). With a configured scoped proxy, Spring will inject a proxy instead of a prototype bean.

The proxy itself will delegate all calls to it to a prototype bean, a new instance each time.

With annotation configuration, you can configure your `@Bean` or `@Component` with

```
@Scope(scopeName = BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

This tells Spring to configure the bean with a proxy that will inherit the target's actual class type and be a prototype.

When you then inject it

```
@Autowired
private MyPrototypeBean bean;
```

`bean` will hold a reference to a proxy object. You can then invoke methods

```
bean.method();
```

and that will delegate to a new instance. This means that each call

```
bean.method();
bean.method();
bean.method();
```

will operate one a new instance, three new instances in the example above. If you only want one instance to invoke those methods, you can extract it from the proxy. See the solution provided [here](http://www.techper.net/2009/06/05/how-to-acess-target-object-behind-a-spring-proxy/)

```
MyPrototypeBean target = null;
if (AopUtils.isJdkDynamicProxy(proxy)) {
    target = (MyPrototypeBean) ((Advised)proxy).getTargetSource().getTarget();
} // won't work for CGLIB classes AFAIK (gotta search)
```